# Pandas to_numeric unable to turn decimal data from db2 into float64

Tags: python, pandas, db2

The process is as below:

1. Script retrieve a column from a data in IBM DB2. The data is of data type = "Decimal"
2. after retrieval, the queries is store in a variable called"result" and being casted into a dataframe column "loading". dtype indicates the data types is being "objects"
3. trying to use to_numeric to turn the "objects" datatype into "float 64". consequently, it turns all data into NaN.
4. I tried different DB2 datatype definition like "vartype","smallint","float" etc. still no luck.

`result = %sql Select leung_chik_wai_college  From COLLEGE_2013_A4`

```
Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013['Loading'] = result
Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013["Loading"] = pd.to_numeric(Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013.Loading, errors='coerce')
Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013.head()
```

[result a not running the to_numeric line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7tUm.jpg)

[ran the to_numeric line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8BCh.jpg)

after running

```
Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013["Loading"] = Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013.Loading.str.replace('\(|\)','').astype('float64')
```

The column is now float64 but all values turned into "NaN"

In case someone is interested in how the raw data looks like:

[image: DB2 definition]

[image: raw csv data as seen in excel]

Comment: does it has something to do with parenthesis in data `"(0.767)"`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you still have parantheses. Remove them then convert:

```
Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013["Loading"] = Tuen_Mun_Weather_2013.Loading.str.replace('\(|\)','').astype('float64')
```

Comment: the column got set into float64 but all the values turned into "NaN"

Comment: @BenjYTLee I'm not sure what the cause is. I ran some sample data and it works. Would you be able to provide a sample of your data for testing?

Comment: thanks @Mohammad for your help. I added screenshot of the data, hope that clarifies. Btw I sort of used a get around to make a new dataframe, put the queries to the new dataframe and use to_numeric. Surprisingly that works, dont know why.

Comment: It could be some issues while reading the dataframe (e.g some extra space after the numbers). Anyway, glad that it worked.